# Regex: search speciale character and remove all spaces + breakable charachter

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to search for a space OR more spaces before [:?!] and replace it with `&nbsp;`

here is my code so far working for many situations except:

`hello[  SPACES  ]?`

it should be

`hello&nbsp;?`

```
text.replace(/ ([:?!])/g, "&nbsp;\$1");
```

Comment: What do you mean by `[ SPACES ]`? If you just mean more than 1 space then just change your code to `text.replace(/ +([:?!])/g, "&nbsp;\$1");`

Comment: Why do you escape `\$1`? Remove the backslash.

Answer (score 0):

#### Using Capturing Group

For one or more spaces followed by either a `:`, `?` or `!` mark. Capture the second part and use it in the replace string.

```js
const str = "Hey  ! Are you busy  ?";
str.replace(/ +([:?!])/g, " $1");
console.log(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

const str = 'Hi my name is mahish dino'
const k=str.replace(/\s/g, '`replace this space with any string or integer')
console.log(k)

using str.replace(/\s/g, '') method you can replace the space with any string.